# c++ beginner question: Is my code wrong or am I misinterpreting the instructions?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment for school due tonight. These are the instructions:

> Summary
>   Linda is starting a new cosmetic and clothing business and would like to make a net profit of approximately 10% after paying all the expenses, which include merchandise cost, store rent, employees’ salary, and electricity cost for the store.
>
> She would like to know how much the merchandise should be marked up so that after paying all the expenses at the end of the year she gets approximately 10% net profit on the merchandise cost.
>
> Note that after marking up the price of > an item she would like to put the item on 15% sale.
>
> Instructions
>   Write a program that prompts Linda to enter:
>
> The total cost of the merchandise
>   The salary of the employees (including her own salary)
>   The yearly rent
>   The estimated electricity cost.
>   The program then outputs how much the merchandise should be marked up (as a percentage) so that Linda gets the desired profit.
>
> Since your program handles currency, make sure to use a data type that can store decimals with a decimal precision of 2.
>
> Grading
>   When you have completed your program, click the Submit button to record your score.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Create constants for the percentage off when items are on sale and profit desired (as a percentage of total merchandise costs)

const double DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE = 0.15;
const double PROFIT_DESIRED = 0.10;

int main(void) 
{
    // Define variables for total cost of merchandise, salary of employees, yearly rent, and estimated electricity cost
    double totalCostOfMerchandise;
    double salaryOfEmployees;
    double yearlyRent;
    double estimatedElectricityCost;

    //Define variables for total costs desired gross income and markup percentage
    double totalCosts;
    double desiredGrossIncome;
    double markupPercentage;

    ////Set the formatting for the screen output of decimal values to 2 decimal places
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

    //Prompt user to enter the total cost of the merchandise
    cout << "Enter total cost of merchandise: " << endl;
    cin >> totalCostOfMerchandise;

   //Output a blank line
   cout << endl;

    //Prompt user to enter the salary of the employees (including own salary)
    cout << "Enter salary of employees (including your own): " << endl;
    cin >> salaryOfEmployees;

    //Output a blank line
    cout << endl;

    //Prompt user to enter the yearly rent
    cout << "Enter yearly rent: " << endl;
    cin >> yearlyRent;

    //Output a blank line
    cout << endl;

    //Prompt user to enter the estimated electricity cost
    cout << "Enter estimated electricity cost: " << endl;
    cin >> estimatedElectricityCost;

    //Output a blank line
    cout << endl;

    //Assign total costs and desiredGrossIncome
    totalCosts = totalCostOfMerchandise + salaryOfEmployees + yearlyRent + estimatedElectricityCost;
    desiredGrossIncome = totalCostOfMerchandise + (totalCostOfMerchandise * PROFIT_DESIRED) + (totalCosts - totalCostOfMerchandise);

    //Assign markup percentage
    markupPercentage = (((desiredGrossIncome/totalCostOfMerchandise)-1)*100) * (1 + DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE);

    //Output markup percentage
    cout << "Merchandise should be marked up " << markupPercentage << "%" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I was given the following values to input to "run checks" on my program:

```
total cost of merchandise: 540000
salary of employees: 80000
yearly rent: 50000
estimated electricity costs: 4000
```

When I input these values, the output is supposed to be 158.61, but I am getting 40.04 instead.

Another set of values to run checks on my program:

```
total cost of merchandise: 600432.50
salary of employees: 99400
yearly rent: 65400
estimated electricity costs: 4356.36
```

When I input these values, the output is supposed to be 162.56, but I am getting 43.90 instead.

I can't figure out if my code is actually wrong or if I am just misunderstanding the instructions.

The way I understand it, the output is supposed to be a percentage referring to how much the products should be marked up. For example, if the cost of merchandise is 100 and the rest of the business costs add up to 100, then the desired gross income would be 110+100 (i.e. 210). 210 is the original cost (100) with a 110% markup added.

Edit: I changed my code. The line that previously read:

```cpp
//Assign markup percentage
markupPercentage = (((desiredGrossIncome/totalCostOfMerchandise)-1)*100) * (1 + DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE);
```

now reads:

```cpp
//Assign markup percentage
markupPercentage = ((desiredGrossIncome/totalCostOfMerchandise)*100) * (1 + DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE);
```

I got rid of the "-1" right before the "*100."

This would mean that if merchandise is "marked up at 100%," there would be no markup. If merchandise that costs 100 is being sold for 200, that would be a "200% markup." I'm not sure that is the proper definition of a markup.

In any case, after this change, my output is way closer to the desired output, but it is still off. In the first example, my output is now 155.04 (desired output is 158.61).

In the second example, my output is now 158.90 (desired output is 162.56).

Again, I am not sure if my code is wrong or of I am just misinterpreting the instructions.

Comment: Whenever possible, make sure you understand how to do a process yourself on paper (and maybe calculator) before trying to teach a computer to do it. What answers do you get for the examples if you try solving them without a computer?

Comment: Please learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Do the results you get in the program fit with your on-paper calculations? When and where does your program start getting it wrong? Also to help debugging, split complex expressions into simpler ones, storing the intermediate result in a temporary variable. That will make it easier to see problems in calculations.

Comment: When I do it without the computer, I am getting an answer that is neither the desired answer nor the answer my program is outputting.

Comment: $100 marked up 15% is $115.  $115 discounted 15% is $97.5.

Comment: There is a potential ambiguity in the language here. The 158.61 answer to your first example is correct. I would call this a markup of 58.61% or a markup to 158.61% of the original price. Your discrepancy is probably due to the issue that my other comment was a hint to point out to you.